# "The executable package.exe aborted with system error code 1073740940" in ABAQUS with the following VUMAT for crystal plasticity

Tags: crystal-structure, finite-element-analysis, software-input-file-request, crystal-plasticity, abaqus

I am new to crystal plasticity simulations and have been studying the concepts from "Introduction to Crystal Plasticity" in Mechanics of Microstructured Materials book. Additionally, I have been going through the publicly available UMAT for crystal plasticity (Huang 1991). I have also come across a paper titled "Comparison of the implicit and explicit finite element methods using crystal plasticity (2007)," where the authors have implemented the model in Abaqus/Explicit environment.

Though I now understand the theoretical basis of the crystal plasticity formulation, I have been unable to implement the model as a VUMAT subroutine, as carried out in the paper. [I received the VUMAT file here](https://imechanica.org/comment/30452), but when I tried to run it I got the error:

```
"The executable package.exe aborted with system error code 1073740940"
```

Comment: I see that it's been 7 months since you signed into any of your 3 stack exchange accounts: https://stackexchange.com/users/19323719/ddsdde?tab=accounts, has there been any progress with this?